# Is using an Ethernet cable with 7/ and 8 swapped (1-2-3-4-5-6-8-7) safe to use with a PoE camera?

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet

A pre-existing wire that was used for an old security cam had 7/8 swapped when I used an Ethernet tester.

I want to repurpose the cable for a new PoE camera.

Would I need to fix the cable or can I just use the existing cable?

Comment: At the camera end it may not matter: https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/what-is-poe-and-how-power-over-ethernet-works

Answer (score 0):

> old security cam had 7/8 swapped

You would need to experiment to see if it works with wires swapped. Newer gear tends to use standard wiring so the more people can just connect the gear.

Otherwise, to repurpose you need standard endings (RJ45 terminations).

If you are adept at cable ends, cut off the ends and attach new RJ45 connectors. I have done this - you need to work carefully and it is an error prone activity.

If you wish to ease your burden, get a new pre-manufactured network cable (RJ45 connectors already attached).

The latter is by far the better approach. I get most all (95% or more) of my cables pre-manufactured.

If the cable is not easily accessible, then get good RJ45 connectors, top quality crimpers, and attach your own ends.

Watch carefully the wire placement and order in the RJ45 connector.

Consider having a contractor do this.

Comment: The American construction technology makes it really easy to lay cables :) In Europe using premade ones is a no-go unless you can hide the excess length behind furniture and run them behind baseboards.

Comment: Unfortunately it'd be very difficult to rerun the cable because it is buried underground. So I'd need to figure out how to attach a new RJ45 connector.

Comment: @gronostaj Slight tangent: “In Europe using premade ones is a no-go unless you can hide the excess length behind furniture and run them behind baseboards.” Do you mean there is no such thing as a short cable in all of Europe? Your profile indicates you are in Poland so does what you describe apply to all of Europe or just Poland?

Comment: @hanson_berkeley One idea is to build your own F to M Ethernet cable that can correct the swap of 7 and 8. But also check if this even matters as Mokubai [points out here](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/what-is-poe-and-how-power-over-ethernet-works).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm not actually knowledgeable enough to speak about entire Europe, but where I live walls aren't hollow - unless you choose a niche construction tech they will be built from concrete blocks, so basically solid for all intents and purposes. The cables are then run on the surface of the blocks and covered with more layers of stuff. If you're running new cables later on when the walls are finished you have to make grooves in the blocks, run cables, patch up the grooves and repaint, so you better get everything right initially.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Premade cables are a thing, but they aren't expected to be run inside walls because there's nowhere to hide the excess length and of course nobody is manufacturing cables in all possible lengths you could need. Also sometimes you have to route the cable to the other side of a wall and it's easier without a plug on it - smaller hole is required and there's less chance of damaging the plug.

Comment: I have added information and cautions about attaching new ends. Do consider a contractor to do this.

Comment: Ahhh! Makes sense. In the three little pigs, the little pig with the straw house and the little pig with the wood house could  easily modify their homes with rational cable runs. But the little pig with a brick house has a small home improvement nightmare on their hands.